# C# Winforms: Scrollbars without AutoScroll

Tags: c#, winforms, autoscroll

I have a TabPage with stuff in it.  A few of my users have tiny screens on which some of that stuff does not fit. When I set AutoScroll true on the TabPage, it adds the scrollbars, as expected. However...

There is a ListBox in this TabPage. The ListBox is positioned such that clicking on it to select a ListItem *causes the TabPage to scroll the entire ListBox into view*, which in turn causes the click to select the wrong ListItem.

if I disable AutoScroll, the ListBox works correctly but the user has no way to scroll the TabPage.

I have tried adding panels and TableLayoutPanels and messing with various combinations of which have AutoScroll and which do not.

I have tried a DLLImport hack that forced an unstyled scrollbar onto the panel, but that scrollbar didn't do anything and it didn't look like the rest of the scrollbars in the application.

*Edit:* Note that some users have larger screens. On *those* screens, there is enough space to display the entire TabPage without scrolling, and it works correctly.

How can I get *scrollbars* without the *auto* scroll behavior?

Comment: You can implement scrollbars manually by relying on VScrollBar & HScrollBar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating a new panel control like this:

```
public class PanelEx : Panel {
  protected override Point ScrollToControl(Control activeControl) {
    return this.DisplayRectangle.Location;
  }
}
```

Put this panel inside your TabPage and set the Dock property to Fill.  Put all of your controls inside that panel instead of the TabPage.